# How to get value of jaxlib.xla_extension.ArrayImpl

Tags: python, arrays, jax

Using `type(z1[0])` I get `jaxlib.xla_extension.ArrayImpl`. Printing `z1[0]` I get `Array(0.71530414, dtype=float32)`. How can I get the actual number `0.71530414`?

I tried `z1[0][0]` because `z1[0]` is a kind of array with a single value, but it gives me an error: `IndexError: Too many indices for array: 1 non-None/Ellipsis indices for dim 0.`.

I tried also a different approach: I searched on the web if it was possible to convert from jaxnumpy array to a python list, but I didn't find an answer.

Can someone help me to get the value inside a `jaxlib.xla_extension.ArrayImpl` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `float(x[0])` to convert `x[0]` to a Python float:

```py
In [1]: import jax.numpy as jnp

In [2]: x = jnp.array([0.71530414])

In [3]: x
Out[3]: Array([0.71530414], dtype=float32)

In [4]: x[0]
Out[4]: Array(0.71530414, dtype=float32)

In [5]: float(x[0])
Out[5]: 0.7153041362762451
```

If you're interested in converting the entire JAX array to a list of Python floats, you can use the `tolist()` method:

```py
In [6]: x.tolist()
Out[6]: [0.7153041362762451]
```

Comment: I get the following error: IndexError: Too many indices for array: 1 non-None/Ellipsis indices for dim 0.

Comment: Then `x` is probably a scalar value. Try `float(x)`.